# Match Unique Value in Column and put all values on that row in to variables

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm working with a CSV with 5 Columns, One of the Columns has unique Values.

```
Fruit,  Number, Car, item,  color
apple,  2,  Chevy,  ball,   blue
apple,  1,  Ford,   ball,   green
orange, 3,  Ford,   string, "red,green"
orange, 5,  Mazda,  key,    red
Banana, 4,  Tesla,  desk,   yellow
```

I need to search for 3 and have it return orange ford string "red,green" as their own variable

i.e. $fruit1 becomes orange $car1 becomes ford $item becomes string and $color bcomes red,green

I can do the search and have it tell me it found 3, but it still just puts runs everything through $fruit1  and if I tell it to write $fruit1 to a file it just get a repeating mess

I Need to Get output to a TXT file like so

```
for #3 
FRUIT=orange 
Car=Ford 
ITEM = string 
COLOR ="red,green"
```

whith each value in a different part of the file/newline

I can't post from the machine the script is on. So values changed to match my example

```
Function LogWrite
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)

   Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}

LogWrite "Started execution of script.ps1"

$masterlist = Import-Csv  ($filepath + "\" + "masterlistfile.csv" )

$FruitName = @()
$NumberName = @()
$Carname = @()
$ItemName = @()
$Colorname = @()


$masterlist |ForEach-Object {
        $FruitName += $_.fruit
        $NumberName += $_.number
        $Carname += $_.car
        $Itemname += $_.item
        $Colorname += $_.color
    }


$number = 3

$FruitIdentified
$CarIdentified
$ItemIdentified
$ColorIdentified

LogWrite "NUmber $number to be searched in masterlistfile "
if ($NumberName -eq $number)
    {
    LogWrite "Number found in the list..."
    $Where = [array]::IndexOf($NumberName, $number)
    LogWrite "Fruit Name :  $FruitrName[$Where] "
    $FruitIdentified = $FruitName[$Where]
    $CarIdentified = $CarName[$Where]
    $ItemIdentified = $ItemName[$Where]
```

}

Comment: Why is it important to have all values in different variables when you can use dot notation to have the values of the filtered object ?

Comment: Why the need for separate variables? Sounds like you want something like this: `Import-Csv input.csv |Where Number -eq 3 |Select * -Exclude Number |Export-Csv output.csv`

Comment: maybe variables isn't the way to go but i need to have it export to a text file with something like "for #3 FRUIT=orange Car=Ford ITEM = string COLOR ="red,green""  but in diffrent parts of the file. its part of a config file i'm working on I've got everything working except for populating the values in the right place

Comment: @JeffMarshall Please add your last comment (your expected output) as part of the question so others can see it, in addition, please share your coding attempt

Comment: Sure thing will do

Comment: What do you mean by "with each value in a different part of the file" ? Is it each value in a new line?

Comment: Yup. updated the post to reflect that

Comment: Ok i think i'm on to something with @Mathias R Jessen answer and something else i found

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to read your CSV and then export the result with your expected output:

```
$number = 3
Import-Csv path/to/csv.csv | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.number -eq $number) {
        "for #$number"
        foreach($prop in $_.PSObject.Properties.Name -ne 'Number') {
            '{0}={2}{1}{2}' -f $prop, $_.$prop, ($null, '"')[$prop -eq 'color']
        }
    }
} | Set-Content path/to/file.ext
```

Note that `Set-Content` will overwrite the export file, if you want to append you would use `Add-Content` as in your function.

To give some context on what the code does:

1. Read the CSV and convert it to an object with `Import-Csv`
2. Loop over all objects and filter where the value of the `Number` property is equal to `$number`.
3. Output `for #$number`, in this example would be `for #3"`.
4. Get all properties of the object using [`PSObject.Properties.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.properties?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) and exclude the `Number` property using [`-ne 'Number'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-eq-and--ne).
5. Loop over the Property Names and output `'{0}={1}' -f $prop, $_.$prop`, here we use the [Format Operator `-f`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#format-operator--f), `{0}` would be the Property Name and `{1}` would be the Property Value. `{2}` will wrap the value with `".."` if the Property Name is `color`.

The output you would be getting using your CSV for input would be:

```
for #3
Fruit=orange
Car=Ford
item=string
color="red,green"
```